# Unable to update plugins in cordova angular

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I am working on ionic/angular project . I updated all my plugins and i am getting now the error [error]

TypeError: Cannot read property ‘Minus’ of undefined
at /Users/mac/ionic-demos/xyzproject/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/translator/src/translator.js:47:37

Please let me know if anyone have idea on this error .

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this as of a few weeks ago. I think it's something to do with not having a fully updated stack. Try "ng update"... the only thing is... not all of us are in a position to just run ng update!